# node.js express req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var PORT = 3000; 

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 
app.post('/', function (req, res) { 
  console.log(req.body); 
  console.log(req.body.username);
  res.end(); 
}); 

app.listen(PORT, function(err){ 
  if (err) console.log(err); 
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT); 
});
```

Test by postman:
Post: http://localhost:3000
{
"username":"userabc",
"password":"passwd1234"
}

But, the result is:
{}
undefined

Comment: Probably you forgot the set the `Content-Type` on the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Content-Type: application/json in the request headers

Answer (score -2):

You need to set Content-Type as application/json on the request.